# create a class to model a list

Tags: java, collections

I have a class named `Person`.This class represents (as the name says) a Person. Now I have to create a class `PhoneBook` to represent a list of `Person`s. How can I do this? I don't understand what means "create a class to represent a list".

```
import java.util.*;

public class Person {

private String surname;
private String name;
private String title;
private String mail_addr;
private String company;
private String position;

private int homephone;       
private int officephone;      
private int cellphone;       

private Collection<OtherPhoneBook> otherphonebooklist;

public Person(String surname,String name,String title,String mail_addr,String company,String position){

    this.surname=surname;
    this.name=name;
    this.title=title;
    this.mail_addr=mail_addr;
    this.company=company;
    this.position=position;

    otherphonebooklist=new ArrayList<OtherPhoneBook>();

}

public String getSurname(){

    return surname;
}

public String getName(){

    return name;
}

public String getTitle(){

    return title;
}

public String getMailAddr(){

    return company;
}

public String getCompany(){

    return position;
}

public void setHomePhone(int hp){

    homephone=hp;
}

public void setOfficePhone(int op){

    officephone=op; 
}

public void setCellPhone(int cp){

    cellphone=cp;
}

public int getHomePhone(){

    return homephone;
}

public int getOfficePhone(){

    return officephone;
}

public int getCellPhone(){

    return cellphone;
}

public Collection<OtherPhoneBook> getOtherPhoneBook(){

    return otherphonebooklist;
}

public String toString(){

    String temp="";

    temp+="\nSurname: "+surname;
    temp+="\nName: "+name;
    temp+="\nTitle: "+title;
    temp+="\nMail Address: "+mail_addr;
    temp+="\nCompany: "+company;
    temp+="\nPosition: "+position;

    return temp;

}
}
```

Comment: It probably means having a list of Person objects as a Phonebook's member.

Comment: `import java.util.*;

/*
* This class rappresent the object 
* list of person
*/

public class PhoneBook { 
 
 private Person person;
  
 public PhoneBook(Person person){
  
  this.person=person;
    
 }
 
 public Person getPerson(){
  
  return person;
 }
 
}`

Comment: @AljoshaBre Can you explain me what you say maybe throught showning me the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the class being named PhoneBook, I assume that you ultimately want to create a mapping between a phone number, and a person.  If this is what you need to do then your PhoneBook class should contain a Map instead of a List (but this may depend on other parameters of the project).

```
public class PhoneBook
{
    private Map<String,Person> people = new HashMap<String,Person>();

    public void addPerson(String phoneNumber, Person person)
    {
        people.put(phoneNumber,person);
    }

    public void getPerson(String phoneNumber)
    {
        return people.get(phoneNumber);
    }
}
```

In the above, the phone number is represented as a String, which is probably not ideal since the same phone number could have different String representations (different spacing, or dashes, etc).  Ideally the Map key would be a PhoneNumber class that takes this all into account in its hashCode and equals functions.

Answer (score 2):

Your `PhoneBook` class will likely have a member like this:

```
private List<Person> book = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

And methods for adding and retrieving `Person` objects to/from this list:

```
public void add(final Person person) {
    this.book.add(person);
}

public Person get(final Person person) {
    int ind = this.book.indexOf(person);
    return (ind != -1) ? this.book.get(ind) : null;
}
```

Note that a `List` isn't the best possible representation for a phone book, because (in the worst case) you'll need to traverse the entire list to look up a number.

There are many improvements/enhancements you could make. This should get you started.

Comment: ok now is's clearer.but this class PhoneBook must have a constructor?

Comment: It could. Your constructor might take an existing list from which to start the book, for example.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by creating a class PhoneBook

```
public class PhoneBook{

Private List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>;

public void addPerson(Person person){
this.personList.add(person);
}

public List getPersonList(){
return this.personList;
}

public Person getPersonByIndex(int index){
return this.personList.get(index);
}
}
```